# How to scrape a dropdown menu with python and BeautifulSoup? (Selenium Needed?)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am very new to anything related to coding, so I am looking for some help. I have looked for a few hours yesterday, and I don't see any content that is really helping or even giving me ideas to try (outside of using Selenium).

I am looking at this website: https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/nhl/stats/2023-2024

I can scrape one seasons worth of data, but there are three things I am looking to do that I currently do not know how to do. First, I would like to know how to scrape the season dropdown menu, so I can scrape multiple years. Additionally, and somewhat related (maybe), I'd like to be able to scrape league dropdown menu, so I can select multiple leagues. Do I need Selenium? I am currently using BeautifulSoup, and I am hoping the code can be adjusted without using Selenium.

My third problem is how to get the link of each player on the same row as his season stats in the data frame; however, I think I can figure that out.

In the end, my goal is to scrape every league in the dropdown menu from 2006-2007 to 2023-2024, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the code right now. I have tried some minor variations, but they all give me a "ValueError: No Objects to concatenate". The for page loop works to get one seasons worth of data. I had to make a slight adjustment, but thanks to another user for that! Like I said, I am pretty new, but my thinking is/was if I can change the page number with a loop, could I not run some type of triple loop that changes the year, league, and page? Maybe that is not possible. Maybe I need Selenium. I just know I need some help or direction on where to get help. No article, video, or posting seems to be helping me in anyway (again, maybe I need Selenium?).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

dfs = []

for year in range (2006-2007, 2023-2024):
        url = f"https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/nhl/stats/{year}?page=1" + str(year) 
        
        
        for page in range(1, 11):
            url = f"https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/nhl/stats/{year}?page=" + str (year) + str(page)
            print(f"Loading {url=}")
            soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
        
            df = (
                pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one(".player-stats")))[0]
                .dropna(how="all")
                .reset_index(drop=True)
            )
            dfs.append(df)

df_final = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 150)
print(df_final) 
df_final.to_csv("data.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how you can get info about all players in all seasons/leagues and store the info in pandas DataFrame:

```py
from io import StringIO
from time import sleep

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_all_year_urls(
    start_url="https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/nhl/stats/2023-2024",
):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(start_url).content, "html.parser")
    return [o["value"] for o in soup.select('option[value*="/stats/"]')]


def get_stats_df(url):
    rv = []
    while True:
        print(url)
        sleep(2)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
        table = soup.select_one("#export-skater-stats-table")
        title = soup.title.text.split(" - ")[-1]
        df = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(table)))[0]

        df.insert(0, "Season_Year", title)
        df.insert(1, "Season_Year_URL", url)

        player_urls = {a.text: a["href"] for a in table.select('a[href*="/player/"]')}
        for name, p_url in player_urls.items():
            df.loc[df.Player == name, "Player_URL"] = p_url

        df = df.dropna(subset=["Team"])
        rv.append(df)

        # is there next page?
        next_page_url = soup.select_one(
            '#export-skater-stats-table ~ div a:-soup-contains("Next page")'
        )
        if not next_page_url:
            break

        url = next_page_url["href"]

    return pd.concat(rv).reset_index(drop=True)


year_urls = get_all_year_urls()

all_dfs = []
for year_url in year_urls:
    df = get_stats_df(year_url)
    print(df.head(3))
    all_dfs.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(all_dfs).reset_index(drop=True)
print(final_df.head(10))
final_df.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
...

https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/ushl/stats/2023-2024
https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/ushl/stats/2023-2024?page=2
https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/ushl/stats/2023-2024?page=3
https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/ushl/stats/2023-2024?page=4
https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/ushl/stats/2023-2024?page=5
https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/ushl/stats/2023-2024?page=6
            Season_Year                                             Season_Year_URL    #             Player                     Team    GP     G     A    TP   PPG   PIM   +/-                                                  Player_URL
0  USHL Stats 2023-2024  https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/ushl/stats/2023-2024  1.0  Jake Sondreal (F)  Dubuque Fighting Saints  38.0  18.0  33.0  51.0  1.34  26.0   1.0  https://www.eliteprospects.com/player/636409/jake-sondreal
1  USHL Stats 2023-2024  https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/ushl/stats/2023-2024  2.0  Matvei Gridin (F)     Muskegon Lumberjacks  38.0  19.0  27.0  46.0  1.21  28.0   1.0  https://www.eliteprospects.com/player/527724/matvei-gridin
2  USHL Stats 2023-2024  https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/ushl/stats/2023-2024  3.0     Zam Plante (C)              Fargo Force  35.0  17.0  28.0  45.0  1.29   2.0  21.0     https://www.eliteprospects.com/player/637043/zam-plante

...
```